# Service worker: Caching requests for one-time URLs without ignoreSearch

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'd like to use a service worker to cache one-time (expiring) URLs.

For example, say I've got an audio file that uses expiring URLs. Each time it's requested, the URL is different (though only the query string differs):

```
http://example.com/foo.mp3?expires=123412341234&secret=abcabcabc
http://example.com/foo.mp3?expires=234523452345&secret=bcabcabca
http://example.com/foo.mp3?expires=345634563456&secret=cfewegfwe
```

I want this to be cached merely as `http://example.com/foo.mp3`, without the query string, so that any subsequent request (even with a new query string) uses the cache.

I know about the "ignoreSearch" option in service worker caches, which seems to have been added to the spec precisely for this use case. But ignoreSearch is not yet implemented in Chrome. Am I out of luck until Chrome implements this, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question.

The solution is to exploit the fact that service worker gives you multiple caches (whose names you control). Just create a separate cache for each file, with each cache containing only one request. I posted code and a detailed writeup at http://www.holovaty.com/writing/service-worker-cache-names/